# can't connect to local web server

Tags: ssh, webserver, ping, wget

when i try to connect to a web server installed on a pc in lan i can't get the index page, the computer is well configured because i can ping and ssh it:

ping

```
$ ping 172.16.69.196
PING 172.16.69.196 (172.16.69.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.69.196: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.69.196: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
^C
--- 172.16.69.196 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.072/0.081/0.091/0.013 ms
```

ssh

```
ssh root@10.0.0.20
The authenticity of host '172.16.69.196 (172.16.69.196)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is e8:8b:cd:a4:db:73:68:86:ea:bf:a9:c4:50:ab:3b:ae.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.16.69.196' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@172.16.69.196's password: 
zynq> exit
Connection to 172.16.69.196 closed.
```

The only thing i can't do is to wget or connect using a web browser

```
 $ wget 172.16.69.196
 --2014-11-19 17:30:54--  http://172.16.69.196/
 Connecting to 172.16.69.196:80... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 3269 (3,2K) [text/html]
 Saving to: ‘index.html.2’

 0% [                                                                                                                                                                                                    ] 0           --.-K/s
```

and nothing happens, but if i do wget from the pc with the web server i get:

```
zynq> wget http://172.16.69.196
Connecting to 172.16.69.196 (172.16.69.196:80)
index.html           100% |*******************************|  3269  --:--:-- ETA
```

how can this be possible?

Comment: iptable is not installed, how can i see if there are other firewall?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is a firewall is blocking access to port 80. Is this Linux? If so what flavor and version? On many latest fedora based distros iptables will not be installed. They use firewalld. If that is the case do the following and try to access the page from other machines.

```
systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

Comment: i'm using a custom linux version, systemctl is not installed, but there is sysctl, is it similar?

Comment: No sysctl is used to modify kernel parameters runtime. How did you check whether iptables is installed or not? You could follow the same process to check for firewalld as well. I'm also looking more closely to your first wget and it says it is connected and request sent but it doesn't seem to transfer content. It may not be firewall after all.

Comment: if i do iptables on the server nothing happens, if i try to connect to the web server on a browser the page keep loading undefinitely